# opera extension scripts and communication between them

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, opera-extension

I made an extension to the firefox using Add-on Builder tool. the extension structure is like,

1. main addon code will run 2 content scripts (1 at run and 1 at ready states of document)
2. the results of content scripts are send to main addon code(using "communication between content script and addon code")
3. the main addon code sends this information to 1 more content script.
4. the content script will add the both results and displays when user clicks on a widget

Example:

**main.js(addon code):**

```
var data = require("self").data;

var paraPanel = require("panel").Panel({

  contentScriptFile: data.url("combine.js")

});

require("page-mod").PageMod({

  contentScriptWhen: 'start',

  contentScriptFile: data.url("content-script1.js"),

  onAttach: function (worker) {

      worker.port.on("para1", function(message) {

      msgfromscript1 = message;

    });

  }

})

require("page-mod").PageMod({

  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',

  contentScriptFile: data.url("content-script2.js"),

  onAttach: function (worker) {

      worker.port.on("para2", function(message) {

     msgfromscript2 = message;

    });

  }

})



require("widget").Widget({

  contentURL: data.url("crack_attack.png"),

  onClick: function() {

    paraPanel.port.emit("add-para", msgfromscript1,msgfromscript2); 

    paraPanel.show();

  }

});
```

**combine.js code:**

```
self.port.on("add-para", function(msgfromscript1,msgfromscript2) {

  var result=msgfromscript1+msgfromscript2;

  document.body.innerHTML = result;

});
```

I want to implement the same functionality as Opera extension. How can I do this communication and the display based on a click functionalities in the Opera browser?

Is there any documentation or example Opera extensions which may help me?

Answer (score 0):

opera extensions documentation: http://dev.opera.com/addons/extensions/
here are two extensions on github: https://github.com/truthee/opera and https://github.com/mywot/opera  hope it helps.